# how to pass an array into update query kdb

Tags: kdb

Hello I have the following code that I would like to find the optimal way of passing the array of any size without having to explicitly do it line by line:

the two arrays are coeffs and tickers. thank you

```
t:update Value:Value*coeffs[0] from (select from t)where Code in `$tickers[0];
t:update Value:Value*coeffs[1] from (select from t)where Code in `$tickers[1];
t:update Value:Value*coeffs[2] from (select from t)where Code in `$tickers[2];
t:update Value:Value*coeffs[3] from (select from t)where Code in `$tickers[3];
t:update Value:Value*coeffs[4] from (select from t)where Code in `$tickers[4];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way you can get it done is using `lj`.

```
q)t:([] n:til 10; Value:1+til 10; Code:10#`a`b`c`d`e)
q)tickers:enlist each "abcdf"
```

Creating `keyed` table `kt` using the `tickers` and `coeffs` :

```
q)kt:([Code:`$tickers] coeffs:2 4 6 8 10 )
q)kt
Code| coeffs
----| ------
a   | 2
b   | 4
c   | 6
d   | 8
f   | 10
```

Now joining the `t` with `kt`

```
q)t:t lj kt
q)t
n Value Code coeffs
-------------------
0 1     a    2
1 2     b    4
2 3     c    6
3 4     d    8
4 5     e
5 6     a    2
6 7     b    4
7 8     c    6
8 9     d    8
9 10    e
```

Updating the table `t` where we have `non-null` `coeff` values

```
q)update Value:Value*coeffs from t where not null coeffs
n Value Code coeffs
-------------------
0 2     a    2
1 8     b    4
2 18    c    6
3 32    d    8
4 5     e
5 12    a    2
6 28    b    4
7 48    c    6
8 72    d    8
9 10    e
```

- With `lj` you will end up having an extra column `coeffs` which you might want to delete.
- This is particularly useful when you have multiple mapping (`tickers->coeffs` , `tickers->delta` etc ) you just need to create one table with all mappings.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming both arrays are of the same length then you could try create a dictionary of `tickers` to `coeffs`:

```
dict:(`$tickers)!coeffs
```

This can then be used in an `update` statement:

```
update Value:Value*1^dict[Code] from t
```

The `1^` is crucial here as indexing into `dict` with a non-existent key will return a null. This notation allows you to [fill](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#fill) null values with `1` thus ensuring `Value` remains the same.